# Is it true that $(1+x)^m \gt 1+mx \;$ for $\; x,m \gt 0 \;$ and $\; x,m \in \Bbb R?$

Tags: real-analysis

Is it true that $(1+x)^m>1+m\cdot x$ for any $x,m>0$ and $x,m\in \Bbb R$?

Notice $m$ was not necessary to be an integer, and specially consider when $m\in (0,1)$.
If it was true, how to proof it?(Without using complex).

Comment: It is true and you can prove it using Binomial theorem.

Comment: Look up *Bernoulli's inequality*

Comment: I proved this just the other day (with the minor $x \to -x$). See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/2176084/269764)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are particularly interested in $m \in (0,1)$.

For $m \in (0,1)$ start with the case where $m = p/q$ is rational.

We have by the AGM inequality

$$(1+x)^{p/q} = ((1+x)^p 1^{q-p})^{1/q} \leqslant \frac{1}{q}(p(1+x) + (q-p)1) = 1 + \frac{p}{q}x = 1 + mx.$$

If $m \in (0,1)$ is irrational take a sequence of rationals $r_n$ converging to $m$.  By the first result

$$(1+x)^{r_n} \leqslant 1 +r_n x.$$

Taking the limit as $n \to \infty$ we get

$$(1+x)^m \leqslant 1 + mx.$$

**Note that the inequality ($\leqslant$) is the reverse of what you posted when $0 < m < 1$.**

Answer (score 1):

This can be proved using binomial expansion: $$(1+x)^m = 1 + m\cdot x + \frac{m(m-1)}{2} x +....
> 1+ m\cdot x$$

Answer (score 1):

We use the derivative of $(1+x)^m$ and the definition of a tangent line along with the convexity of $(1+x)^m$ to derive the desired result

---

To accomplish this we first find the slope at $0$
$$\left.\frac{d}{dx} (1+x)^m\right|_{x=0} = \left.m(1+x)^{m-1}\right|_{x=0} = m$$
We now note that at $x_0=0$ we have $y_0 = (1+0)^m = 1$
Therefore, our tangent line is the function
$$y_0 +m(x-x_0) = 1+mx$$
Since $(1+x)^m$ is convex on this interval (check the second derivative) we can say that, $\forall m \notin (0,1)$ and $x>0$,
$$(1+x)^m \gt  1+mx$$
Note that the convexity argument gets a little tougher if we let $m<0$, though the inequality still holds for $x>0$

Answer (score 0):

Consider the map :

$$f:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R},x\mapsto(1+x)^m-1-mx$$

Here is its derivative :

$$\forall x\in[0,1],f'(x)=m\left((1+x)^{m-1}-1\right)$$

Since $m-1\le0$, we know that $x\mapsto(1+x)^{m-1}$ is decreasing on $[0,1]$; hence :

$$\forall x\in[0,1],\,f'(x)\le0$$

and so $f$ is decreasing. But $f(0)=0$ and so $f(x)\le0$ for all $x\in[0,1]$.

**Old and inappropriate answer ... (considered that $m$ was an integer, $m\ge2$)**

This can also be proved by induction, starting with $m=2$ ($x>0$ is fixed) :

$$(1+x)^m=1+2x+x^2>1+2x$$

Assuming that $(1+x)^m>1+mx$ for some $m\ge2$, we see that :

$$(1+x)^{m+1}=(1+x)^m(1+x)>(1+mx)(1+x)=1+(m+1)x+mx^2>1+(m+1)x$$